# How do you mock the querystring in a WCF service?

Tags: wcf, query-string, moq

I have a WCF service which has methods that depend on reading values (OData) from the http request's querystring. I'm trying to write unit tests which inject in mock values into the querystring, then when I call the method it would use these mock values rather than erroring due to the request context not being available.

I've tried using [WCFMock](http://wcfmock.codeplex.com/) (which is based on Moq) however I don't see a way to set or get the querystring from the WebOperationContext that it provides.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the IOC pattern to solve this, creating an IQueryStringHelper interface that is passed into the constructor of the service. If it isn't passed in then it'll default to use the "real" QueryStringHelper class. When running test cases, it'll use an overloaded service constructor to pass in the TestQueryStringHelper instance, which lets you set a mock value for the querystring.

Here is the querystring helper code.

```
public interface IQueryStringHelper {
        string[] GetParameters();
    }

    public class QueryStringHelper : IQueryStringHelper {
        public string[] GetParameters() {
            var properties = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties;
            var property = properties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] as HttpRequestMessageProperty;
            string queryString = property.QueryString;
            return queryString.Split('&');
        }
    }

    public class TestQueryStringHelper : IQueryStringHelper {
        private string mockValue;

        public TestQueryStringHelper(string value) {
            mockValue = value;
        }

        public string[] GetParameters() {
            return mockValue.Split('&');
        }
    }
```

And the service implementation:

```
    public partial class RestService : IRestService {
            private IAuthenticator _auth;
            private IQueryStringHelper _queryStringHelper;

            public RestService() : this(new Authenticator(), new QueryStringHelper()) {
            }

            public RestService(IAuthenticator auth, IQueryStringHelper queryStringHelper = null) {
                _auth = auth;
                if (queryStringHelper != null) {
                    _queryStringHelper = queryStringHelper;
                }
            }
}
```

And how to consume it from a test case:

```
string odata = String.Format("$filter=Id eq guid'{0}'", "myguid");
var service = new RestService(m_auth,new TestQueryStringHelper(odata));
var entities = service.ReadAllEntities();
```

Hopefully this helps someone else.